# Do I need both JRE 1.6 and JRE 1.7?

Tags: java

I have both JRE 1.6 and JRE/JDK 1.7 installed on my PC. Do I need both JREs, or can I just keep JRE 1.7 and uninstall JRE 1.6?

I only occasionally have anything to do with the JDK so I'm largely unfamiliar with the Java world. Mostly I just need the JRE for the misc application that needs it.

I do know from PHP web development experience that I need both PHP 5.1 and 5.3 due to deprecation versus enhancement issues, so I was not sure if JRE 1.6 and 1.7 were similar.

Please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have something that specifically depends on JRE 1.6, you can just keep 1.7.

In general, the Java language is very backwards compatible, so such dependencies on older versions are rare.

There is one special concern with the 6-to-7 leap, though: Oracle changed the licensing model for Java distribution, so you must be aware that OpenJDK 1.7 and Oracle Java 1.7 are **not quite the same**. So if you have Oracle JDK 1.6, you can't necessarily replace it with OpenJDK 1.7 -- you might have software that depends on the proprietary Oracle-only packages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the caveat about Oracle. I'm doing some PC housekeeping so I'm currently upgrading all software. I was horrified to learn during this upgrade process that Oracle now owns OpenOffice (I already knew about Java and MySQL). Let's hope that Stallman's predictions don't come true...

Comment: @Borealid Btw can you elaborate more on the rare dependencies of older versions? Isn't JRE 1.7 **100%** compatible with JRE 1.6 and older, JRE 1.6 100% compatible with JRE 1.5 and older, and so on? (btw I'm talking about the runtime for the average user, not the compiler)

Comment: @Pacerier No. As a trivial example, you could have code that checks for a "correct" version of Java and was written before 1.7's release. Also, as with any language where bugs are fixed, software that depends on the bugs no longer functions. Java's not 100% backwards compatible, it's just "very" much so, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

JRE 7 should be backward compatible with 6.  Since you said JRE, and not JDK, I'd say you're safe to remove JRE 6.

Answer (score 0):

if you have JRE 1.7 then I think you don't need the JRE 1.6. you will get all the features of JRE 1.6 in JRE 1.7

Comment: I think you meant "if you have JRE 1.7 then I think you don't need the JRE 1.6". :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have JRE 7u45, you may have issue while reading system properties from JNLP files, in this case better to use java 6