# Application Performance issues due to multiple JRE versions

Tags: java

Hi for suppose i have multiple JRE versions(1.6.1 till 1.7) on a single machine and one of the application is supposed to use JRE 1.6, at the same time another application is using JRE 1.7.0_17 ,Will that cause any performance issues???Please advice

Comment: Experiencing delay when using Java screens of an applicaiton,(I can clearly see that after installing multiple JRE versions)

Comment: You need not to have multiple JRE's.

Comment: What I mean is , If you are having JRE 1.7 on your machine, your 1.6 app must be run with 1.6.

Comment: But if i have multiple JRE i mean 1.7.0.*

Answer (score 0):

First in hand, since you are talking about JRE (not JDK), you need not to have multiple JRE's.

JRE 1.7 supports JRE 1.6 because of backward compatibility. Just remove 1.6 and connect to 1.7.

Might helpful : [Do I need both JRE 1.6 and JRE 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047032/do-i-need-both-jre-1-6-and-jre-1-7)

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't cause any (big) problems. Each JVM  will run as a seperate process and will be handled independently by the OS. If your apps use the same resources, then there might be a deadlock somewhere.

As a general note (which applies to any process), having more processes will consume more CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you Please brief in detail more possibilities for deadlock with multiple JRE versions.

That will definetly help me.

Comment: @AdityaNamburi - Simplest case of dead lock / delay could be - *if you are doing IO and both process try to read the same file(s)*

Comment: @AdityaNamburi - Also, the same program would probably run faster on jre7 (not always) when compared to jre6 because of numerous enhancements brought in jre7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple `JRE` installed on the same machine. And you can have one project configured with one version another with another version.

But if you run Higher version of Java compiled code on a `JRE` having lower version, you might face some issues.

It **will not slow machine**. A machine can have multiple `JVM` on single machine.

Comment: That was not slowing my machine- But my Application